# How to show current date and time like 11 December 2015 11:20 AM using jquery, AM needs to show like superscript

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

How to  show current date and time like 11 December 2015 11:20 AM  using jQuery, AM needs to show like superscript.please check my fiddle and image http://fiddle.jshell.net/kannankds/qtrnzsp6/

```
<div>
<asp:Label ID="cTime" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" BackColor="#ffff00" 
Font-Bold="true" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way but little more as you wanted.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth(); //Removed +1
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','Septempber','October','November','December'];
var minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes();
var hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getHours() : d.getHours();
var ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? '<sup>PM<sup>' : '<sup>AM<sup>';
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = d.getDate() + ' ' + months[month]+' '+d.getFullYear()+' '+hours +':'+minutes + ' ' + ampm;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: `month` now contains the right number to *show* the date but unfortunately the wrong index for *looking up* the month name in the `months` array. Just leave out the `+1` after `d.getMonth()`.

Comment: Ya missed that, had this code for my old project, thanks by the way @cars10

Comment: Updated the Month above.

Answer (score 3):

Use this script

```
document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = formatAMPM();

function formatAMPM() {
var d = new Date(),
    minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
    hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
    ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? '<sup>PM<sup>' : '<sup>AM<sup>',
    months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
    days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
return days[d.getDay()]+' '+months[d.getMonth()]+' '+d.getDate()+' '+d.getFullYear()+' '+hours+':'+minutes+ampm;
}
```